When does an asymptotic expansion of moments yield an expansion of the generating function?
Let $X_N$ be a sequence of random variables and let the moments have an asymptotic expansion
$$\langle X_N^k \rangle \sim \sum_{\ell \geq 0} m_{k,\ell} N^{-\ell}$$
in the sense of Poincaré. Then under what circumstances can I conclude that (for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$)
$$\langle e^{i x X_N} \rangle \sim \sum_{\ell \geq 0} F_{\ell}(x) N^{-\ell}$$
for some sequence $F_{\ell}$? There is a trivial case in which the error bound for the moments is summable over $k$, so let's assume that's not the case. My guess is it should be somehow related to the tails of $X_N$ decaying fast at infinity uniformly in $N$. For simplicity one can assume that $m_{k,0}$ are the Gaussian moments since this is the case I'm interested in.
